# How to compare two empirical CDFs obtained from current status data

Tags: nonparametric, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, interval-censoring, anderson-darling-test

I have failure time information of a product in the form of current status data, which looks something like this.

| Observed Time($t_i$) | failed ? ($y_i$) |
| --- | --- |
| 5 hrs | 1 |
| 6 hrs | 0 |
| 5 hrs | 0 |
| 7 hrs | 1 |

Essentially each row represents an observation. In the first column, we have the observation time ($t_i$) of an item and in the second column, we have information regarding whether the item failed within the observed time ($t_i$) or not (1 means failed and 0 means did not fail). So, the observed time is an upper bound of the failure time if the item did fail and the observed time is a lower bound of the failure time if the item did not fail.

I derive the empirical CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function) of the failure time from this data using the  [method proposed by Turnbull](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285518).

Let's say I have two such datasets and I derive two empirical CDFs from each of them. How do I compare those empirical CDFs.

Can we use the usual methods like the `Anderson-Darling test` or the `KS Test` to compare the two CDFs? I am not sure because in the usual applications of those tests, we usually have the exact data of failure times and not current status data. So, the empirical cdf at a time $t_i$ is calculated simply as (Number of items with failure time $\le t_i$)/(Total number of items). But in case of current status data, the CDFs at time $t_i$ would be calculated in a different way.

Comment: Do you have any censoring of failure times?

Comment: @Glen_b yes I have 'current status data' which can be considered a special case of interval-censored data - where if the event `failed=1`, then the interval is (0, $t_i$] and if the event `failed=0`, then the intervals are [$t_i$,infinity). Current status data is also called CASE 1 interval-censored data.